# Accumulate a Function Over a List of Monads (Maybe)

Tags: list, haskell, option-type, monads

I'm learning Haskell as a way of getting to grips with a new programming paradigm. I'm getting hung up on a specific, probably basic, issue. While I'm finding lots of documentation and other stack overflow questions, I feel like I am getting lost in the noise of other people's examples when trying to figure out how to get this working.

Critically, I'm not Just (aha) looking to get this working, I am also looking to understand the abstraction, which hitherto I'm definitely failing to do.

Let us say we have a list of Ints

```
x = [1, 2, 5]
```

To get the product of these Ints, I know that I can do:

```
result = foldr (*) 1 x
```

In the case where this list instead is of Maybe Ints, I'm trying to work out how to do *something like*

```
x = [Just 1, Just 2, Just 5, Nothing]

res_from_x = <magic_fold> (*) 1 x
-- res from x is Nothing

y = [Just 2, Just 3]
res_from_y = <magic_fold> (*) 1 y
-- res from y is 6
```

I'm sure there is a straightforward and idiomatic abstraction to this, but I've not managed to figure out how to manipulate fold or use foldM to meet this end.

Comment: A note unrelated to your question: for primitive (specifically, fully-strict) operations like `+` or `*`, you should typically use `foldl'` (not `foldl`!) rather than `foldr`. Or just use `sum` / `product`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks (I had been dithering about changing over)

Comment: `foldM (fmap . (*)) 1`; `product . map Ap`

Comment: @DanielWagner - impressively concise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any magic fold, you just need a suitable operator to fold with. Note that your problem doesn't really have anything to do with lists, you could just as well ask for

```
x₀ = Just 5
x₁ = Nothing
res_from_x = <magic_combo> (*) x₀ x₁
-- result is `Nothing`

y₀ = Just 2
y₁ = Just 3
res_from_y = <magic_combo> (*) y₀ y₁
-- result is `Just 6`
```

So you need some combinator that takes an operation `Int -> Int -> Int` and lifts it to an operation `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`. Notice further that this combinator shouldn't actually require the operands to have type `Int` or any other particular type, because only the operation should be dealing with the actual values. So the type we're looking for seems to be

```
    (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
```

Let's [ask Hoogle about that](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+Maybe+a+-%3E+Maybe+b+-%3E+Maybe+c), and it'll come back with

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

...using the fact that [`Maybe` is an instance of the `Applicative` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1120).

(Of course, the fact that `liftA2` has the correct type doesn't prove that it actually does the right thing; you should always read the documentation and run some simple tests before using something that Hoogle suggests! But, in this case the first hit on Hoogle is indeed exactly what you should use.)

Comment: Thankyou for an answer which steps me through the logic and explains how you came to the conclusions, while also giving me a way to solve analogous problems in future cases. Exemplary.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that `foldr (*) 1` expects a value of type `[Int]` (we'll assume `Int`, rather than `Num a => a` for simplicity), while you have a value of type `[Maybe Int]`. You can bridge this gap by changing both your value and the expected argument type to the common type `Maybe [Int]` as follows.

1. Use `sequence` to collapse a `[Maybe Int]` value to a single `Maybe [Int]` value.

   ```
   > sequence [Just 1, Just 2, Just 5, Nothing]
   Nothing
   > sequence [Just 2, Just 3]
   Just [2,3]
   ```
2. Use `fmap` to "lift" `foldr (*) 1` from `[Int] -> Int` to `Maybe [Int] -> Maybe Int`.

The end result is

```
> fmap (foldr (*) 1) (sequence [Just 1, Just 2, Just 5, Nothing])
Nothing
> fmap (foldr (*) 1) (sequence [Just 2, Just 3])
Just 6
```

This is similar to the use of `liftA2` and `liftM2` in the other answers, except we're lifting the entire fold instead of folding with a lifted operator.

The "magic" function (which we'll give its fully generalized type) is

```
import Control.Applicative

magicFoldr :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t (f a) -> f b
magicFoldr f z = fmap (foldr f z) . sequenceA
```

(The use of `sequenceA` imposes the `Applicative` constraint on the `Maybe` instance as well as "upgrading" the `Foldable` constraint on the `[]` instance to a `Traversable` constraint.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`liftM2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2), for example:

```
foldr (liftM2 (*)) (Just 1) [Just 2, Just 3]          -- Just 6
foldr (liftM2 (*)) (Just 1) [Just 2, Just 3, Nothing] -- Nothing
```

or, to extract it to a new function:

```
magicFoldr f i = foldr (liftM2 f) (return i)
magicFoldr (*) 1 [Just 2, Just 3]          -- Just 6
magicFoldr (*) 1 [Just 2, Just 3, Nothing] -- Nothing
```

Update: or, as @leftaroundabout suggests, `liftA2` is more generic (then replace `return` with `pure` above)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer to solve the immediate problem, that is correct, but I felt that the other answer I received was more complete.

Comment: @PhilipAdler I do agree, that the other answer is better :)